# Create a mark function from a normal law

Tags: algorithm, math, normal-distribution

I'm working on an android application and at some point, I retrieve a value contained between -100 and 100 which follow a normal law (I don't have the parameters of this law).

I would like to create a function which returns me a mark on 20 but to avoid to have all marks between 8 and 12, I would like to "stretch" values around 0.

For example, a variation of 1 around the 0 will give me a 0.5 point of difference in the mark, and a 1 point variation around the 100 will give me a 0.01 point of difference in the mark.

Is there any algorithm/function/trick that will gave me this possibility ? Which could be the conditions or requirement ? Is there any library available that will give me this possibility ? (I search but didn't found...)

Thank you !

Comment: You appear to be asking to convert the value of a normal variable to the corresponding population percentile. This is not a programming question - ask on stats instead.

Comment: Or use a SD of around 33 and the calculator here http://bayes.bgsu.edu/nsf_web/jscript/normal_cdf/normal_icdf.htm to give your x values for your ranks